# How to disable Mutual Authentication for a certain URL

Tags: spring, ssl-certificate, jetty

I a project I am working on, we configured our current Jetty Server with the following configs:

```java
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();

        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(tlsCfg.tlsKeystoreLocation);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(tlsCfg.tlsKeystorePassword);
        sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(tlsCfg.useMutualAuth);
        sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols("TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3");
        // cipher suites that are not secure are properly removed by default constructor.
        if (tlsCfg.useMutualAuth) {
            sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath(tlsCfg.tlsTruststoreLocation);
            sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword(tlsCfg.tlsTruststorePassword);
        }

        JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(getSecureBaseURI(port), sslContextFactory, rc);
```

Our application has status resource which looks like the following:

```java
    @Path("status")
    public class StatusResource {


        @Autowired(required = false) // optional dependencies are not supported by @Inject
        public StatusResource(Supplier<List<Status>> subStatusesSupplier) {
            this.subStatusesSupplier = subStatusesSupplier;
        }

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Status status() {
            ...
            return status;
        }
    }
```

For our Operations Team it would be very helpful if this Endpoint (**and only this endpoint**) would not require the MutalAuthentication and the Tls-Settings.

Is there an option to exclude one endpoint from the whole SslContextFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

TLS/SSL occurs way before the request is even made.

The request contains the URI to the endpoint that you want to limit the mutual authentication on.

The only way you can accomplish this is with 2 ServerConnectors, each with their own `SslContextFactory`, one with mutual auth, one without.